# phpMyAdmin style web client for AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there an available web client to manage the `mysql` database in **AWS RDS**? Something like **phpMyAdmin** preferably.

I used **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** to setup the server btw.

Any ideas? Still new to AWS. Thanks

Comment: I'm new to AWS too, hope you found a solution since no comment is marked as one? If so, what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS for MySQL does not have a graphical interface, and nothing can be installed on the RDS server, itself since the design of RDS is such that you don't have access to the machine where it runs.

If you really wanted phpMyAdmin (pma), you could install it on an EC2 instance and point it to RDS, then enter the address of the EC2 instance in your browser.  Theoretically, you could install it on your app server, but a separate instance would probably be better.

The web-based design of pma is inherently limited, though, and your interests might be better served by a locally-installed query browser tool on your workstation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want phpmyadmin access the RDS server simple way are ,

1. install the phpmyadmin on you local system if you want to or any
   webserver
2. edit the config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin folder in linux its located `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

   find  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] ='localhost';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] ='RDSServername.rds.amazonaws.com';`
3. restart the web server

Comment: Ok which OS you are using ? Linux or Windows ? did you find the config.inc.php and that line will be at the end of the file and comment you need to uncommment it

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL workbench or phpMyAdmin on local machines to connect to AWS RDS instance.

1. For mysql workbench
   If you are using MySQL workbench then its pretty straight forward. Steps 1. Click on new MySQL connection.
2. Give any Connection name for your reference
3. In hostname field, add the endpoint URL which you can get from AWS RDS console. (dont add :3306, its default)
4. In username field, add the username you had added while creating RDS instance.
5. Keep other params as it is and click on Test Connection.It will ask for password which you had added while creating RDS instance.
6. If all the input params are correct, you are connected to the database